# Can't fail Underground Undercover

Tags: fallout-4

I wanted to go through the Railroad and Brotherhood quest as much as possible without killing each other before beating the game with the Minutemen. I can't start the Minutemen quest until I've failed Underground Undercover. So I killed a scientist but then nothing happens. I found out you need to complete Tradecraft, which I did. I tried to complete all the quests that come after that, but Mercer Safehouse was glitched because I have the Tactical Thinking quest open and P.A.M. won't talk to me. Since those quests aren't technically Tradecraft I don't know if they matter.

Is there a way to fail Underground Undercover under these circumstances, and is there a way to fix P.A.M.?

I also found a bug where you can't talk to Desdemona, and that may be part of the issue.

Comment: PAM won't talk to you - do you mean she can't be reprogrammed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to get banished from the Institute.

> Under most circumstances, **becoming enemies with the Institute
>   immediately fails Underground Undercover** and any active, related
>   Railroad quests and starts Burning Cover instead.

There are [a few ways to get banished](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Banished_from_the_Institute#Detailed_walkthrough), but the following one seems appropriate:

> - Kill any named Institute personnel.

This seems to be the easiest way for your purposes, especially since you *almost* did this anyway :)